# Directory.Delete(path, true) throws IOException "The directory is not empty"

Tags: c#, .net, directory

I have code that creates a temp directory, does stuff, and then deletes the directory when it is done.  The problem is that even though I specify true for the recursive parameter, it still throws an IOException saying "The directory is not empty".
Here's what I have for code:

```
DirectoryInfo info = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(tempdir, "temp"));
try{
    PopulateDir(info);
    foreach (FileInfo file in info.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)){
        DoStuff(file);
    }
}
finally{
    info.Delete(true);// note: this is apparently functionally identical to Directory.Delete(info.FullName, true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `info.EnumerateFiles` was the issue.  I got that idea from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4102674/1366594).
I switched that to `info.GetFiles` and I was then able to delete the directory after.