# Selectively disable Process features

Tags: wpf, winapi, user32

I've been trying to create a WPF application which will be a proactive filter trying to limit user activity. I've controlled mouse and keyboard through Win32 API. Now another requirement is to let the user open every other application/file through the WPF one.

I don't want to disable the user's clicking ability while he's inside a process. I've tried to disable file access but with no luck.

I have control over the user while launching a new process but what if he opens a file within the process?

Can I just disable 'New' and 'Open' options or the complete file menu in any other process like Microsoft Word?

Comment: This is a very unproductive avenue.  They'll simply kill your app and use, say, Windows Explorer to do whatever they want.  Machines are locked down by their admins, not by you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971180/how-to-monitor-process-io-activity-using-c). But the problem is, that this just tells what files are currently being accessed by the given process. So you can maybe kill the process in that moment:D Or warn the user. But as far as i know, you cannot create a semi-layer between another process and his system requests (like is the file [read/write] access request).

EDIT: Maybe there is another option. If these restricted files are known to you, and there is just small amount of them... then you can just lock them for your process and disable access to them for every other processes.